# Recreating a shape in AI or Sketch

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes, sketch-app

Can anyone recommend me a tutorial or give me some indications on how I might be able to recreate this shape in AI or Sketch?

[image]

It doesn't seem so complicated, I'm sure that might be just one simple trick to achieve a curved line like this one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'trick' with drawing this kind of shape is to break it down into its constituent parts. In this case, quarter circles and 45 degree angle lines should do it. The following screenshot shows what I managed to achieve in about 5 minutes, it's pretty rough, but it shows the principle. At the top are some of the components and below is the shape that I've assembled from those parts:

[image]

Using smart guides and/or snapping to objects and points helps with getting everything to join up nicely.

Your specific approach would depend on whether you want to exactly recreate the reference image or create something of your own in a similar style. If you need to recreate the logo exactly then you would want to work over the top of it to match the angles and alignment exactly.

Comment: Good answer, +1. Another way is I would have simply used the Rounded Rectangle Tool with a desired radius (it's easier to control the radius like this) rotated at a 45 degrees angle. Duplicate, rotate and place :D

Comment: The rounded rectangle idea was my first thought too because it creates the lines and curves in one hit, but I went with the above route because it's easier to accurately get the concentric curves that this particular design needs by starting with circles.

Comment: @Chris WOW! Super nice! Can you share the source file with me? To have a better understanding of how this is built and play around with it? I'm a total disaster on working with illustrations.

Comment: If you do not want to share anything, can you guide me where should I start, how can I start? Should I use Adobe Illustrator? How can I use smart guides / snapping to objects to achieve this? It's pretty hard for me to hard guess everything.

Comment: My example was created in Adobe Illustrator, but I didn't save the file so I can't send it to you. You'll learn much better by recreating it yourself anyway. If you're unfamiliar with terms like smart guides and snapping to points, objects etc then searching those things on google should serve up plenty of basic tutorials. Maybe look for a "basic path operations" tutorial or something like that to get you started.

Comment: Practice and patience my friend. It's taken me over twenty years to get to the point where I can throw something like that together in 5 minutes. You're not going to get there in a few hours. Frankly, unaccepting my answer because you can't master the solution in a couple of days is straight up rude.

Answer (score -1):

go to illustrator there is an image trace option in it.

open illustrator

create new document

add this artwork there

click on image trace

try different settings until you acheive what you want.

tip 1 - seperate that shape in photoshop and import it into illustrator and then trace.

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/tracing-artwork-live-trace-or.html